# Listening "folder opening" events in windows(java)

Tags: java, windows

I mean whenever we open a folder, a event is definitely created somwhere.
So I would want to know how to add a listener to that event.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible using pure Java code. You might have to write your own DLLs.

Comment: What do you want to achieve just by knowing directory is OPEN? Not sure about OPEN, but you can try to listen for CREATE, DELETE or MODIFY event on a directory see this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: what do you mean with "whenever we open a folder"? Folders inside of the windows explorer.exe? And who in hell is "we"?

Comment: I mean any folder.  For example 'program files'in local disk c

Comment: I asked this question because I was curious how a virus multiplys by just opening folders.

Comment: it doesnt. If a virus spreads seemingly uncontrollably it has some sort of loading-mechanism and probably a lot of timers and/or scheduled tasks - all of which can be stopped.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> a event is definitely created somwhere

... no. That'd be a **massive** security risk since every app could hook into every other app - this is only possible inside of filesystem drivers and kernel driver filters, if you want to create a native filesystem filter driver i recommend starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Hardware/ff557565(v=vs.85).aspx) and after you have read that [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548202(v=vs.85).aspx) might be a great help.

Comment: Sorry for the 'we'.  I searched and found windowlistener events. Is it useful?

Comment: Well specializt I understood your answer. But I think intended to exploit that security risk. Is it possible?

Comment: No, not reliably - its a game of luck and of course unsupported

Comment: Since you stress, that raising an event would be a *"**massive** security risk"*, you should definitely point out, how registering for an event poses any kind of risk, security or otherwise. Especially when you move on to explain that said callback mechanism exists.

Comment: registering for events like that is a security problem since its basically spyware-functionality, almost everyone who asks for such knowledge has malevolent intentions - which is proven by his words. Developers who actually need to know these things for their work are usually able to search through MSDN themselves, they probably even have access to professional education sources and dont need any internet advice. But since i know that you wont stop asking : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761885(v=vs.85).aspx. You just supported the creation of spyware, congrats.

Comment: But where's the security risk specifically? I don't see one. Running arbitrary code is a security risk. Providing the functionality to hook into filesystem operations isn't (given the restrictions for kernel modules).

Comment: you may just be the only person on this entire planet who doesnt see a security risk in spyware-functionality.